# Using FLWOR to get data from another table

Tags: sql-server, xquery, xquery-sql, flwor

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblStepList]
(
    [ToDoId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [xml] NOT NULL
)
```

And the `Data` column is of type `XML` and contents like this:

```
<Steplist>
  <Step>
    <StepId>e36a3450-1c8f-44da-b4d0-58e5bfe2a987</StepId>
    <Rank>1</Rank>
    <IsComplete>false</IsComplete>
    <TextReadingName>bug-8588_Updated3</TextReadingName>     
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <StepId>4078c1b1-71ea-4578-ba61-d2f6a5126ba1</StepId>
    <Rank>2</Rank>
    <TextReadingName>reading1</TextReadingName>
  </Step>
</Steplist>'
```

I want to update each row of the table with my new xml to look with new node named TextReadingId after TextReading name

I have a secondary table  with text reading values stepid and textreadingid

```
StepId                                TextReadingId 
---------------------------------------------------
e36a3450-1c8f-44da-b4d0-58e5bfe2a987    118
4078c1b1-71ea-4578-ba61-d2f6a5126ba1    119
d466a8ee-9214-4b9c-94f9-2117f5dffe93    401
```

And I want my TextReadingId values to come from the table above

```
 <Steplist>
          <Step>
            <StepId>e36a3450-1c8f-44da-b4d0-58e5bfe2a987</StepId>
            <Rank>1</Rank>
            <IsComplete>false</IsComplete>
            <TextReadingName>bug-8588_Updated3</TextReadingName>    
          <TextReadingId>118</TextReadingId>   
          </Step>
          <Step>
            <StepId>4078c1b1-71ea-4578-ba61-d2f6a5126ba1</StepId>
            <Rank>2</Rank>
            <TextReadingName>reading1</TextReadingName>
          <TextReadingId>401</TextReadingId> 
          </Step>
        </Steplist>';
```

This is what I tried but it is not working as expected

```
DECLARE @i int;

SELECT
    @i = s.data.value('count(/Steplist/Step)', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM 
    tblStepList s

SET data.modify('insert <TextReadingId>{sql:variable("@i")}</TextReadingId> as last into (/Steplist/Step[sql:variable("@i")])[1]')

PRINT @i
```

[Here is another answer that helped but it does not join with my other table for the results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69727258/sql-update-xml-column-in-a-table-recursively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to rebuild each `Step` node and then aggregate it back up using `FOR XML`

Within the correlated subquery, we do the following:

- Break out the `Step` nodes using `.nodes()`
- Left join `StepReading` on the `StepId` node value
- Create an *unnamed* column containing a new `Step` node...
- ... which contains all the children from the existing one using `./*` ...
- ... and an extra child node `TextReadingId` with the value from `StepReading`
- Then aggregate back up using `FOR XML`

```sql
UPDATE sl
SET Data = (
    SELECT v.Step.query('
<Step>{./*,
        if (not(./TextReadingId)) then
            <TextReadingId>{sql:column("sr.TextReadingId")}</TextReadingId>
        else ()
        }
</Step>
    ')
    FROM sl.Data.nodes('/Steplist/Step') v(Step)
    LEFT JOIN StepReading sr ON sr.StepId = v.Step.value('(StepId/text())[1]','uniqueidentifier')
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Steplist'), TYPE
)
FROM tblStepList sl;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fbb25/21)

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: @Charlieface How can I make sure this can be rerun and does not insert duplicate TextReadingId nodes and also the TextReadingId is inserted directly after textReadingname node if it exists?

Comment: OK have modified for you

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks a lot. Can I make sure it is after textReadingname node if it exists?

Comment: It will always place this new node last, and the new edit will only insert if it's not there already

Comment: @Charlieface I have almost a million records in my db and this is taking so slow. Is there a way to optimize your query?

Comment: Please share a query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Yous should have an index on `StepReading (StepId) INLCUDE (TextReadingId)` or similar. Adding `WHERE sl.Data.exist('/Steplist/Step/TextReadingId') = 0` at the end, and removing the `if(not` may also speed things up, see fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fbb25/22

Comment: @Charlieface I just did share it . FYI I use CTE for StepReading

Comment: @Charlieface https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkewQdlwK

Comment: Change the XQuery at the top to use `text()` and more sensible data types `x.XmlCol.value('(StepId/text())[1]', uniqueidentifier') as StepId, x.XmlCol.value('(TextReadingName/text())[1]', 'int') as [TextReadingName]`. Dump the whole of the CTE `tblWOInstructionsteptextreading` into a well-indexed temp table. Then join on that.

Comment: @Charlieface Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69843694/xquery-sql-select-node-only-if-exists

Comment: The answer there looks OK

Comment: @Charlieface check this  https://stackoverflow.com/q/69854955/3038042